Solve $\left| 3x+2\right| \geq 4$

Solve $\left| 3x+2\right| \geq 4$

If $3x+2 \geq 0$:
$3x+2 \geq 4 \Rightarrow x \geq \dfrac{2}{3}$
If $3x+2 < 0$:
$-(3x+2) \geq 4 \Rightarrow -3x-2 \geq 4 \Rightarrow -x \geq 2 \Rightarrow x \leq -2$
And the problem is solved. My question is with the second case. By definition, $\left| x \right| =  c \Rightarrow x=\pm c$. But if I were to write $3x+2 \geq -4$, I would end up with $x \geq -2$. But it seems to me it shouldn't matter whether I write down $-(3x+2)\geq4$ or $3x+2 \geq -4$, yet the answers are different, so what is the difference? Or what is the mistake I made in my assumptions?

Where does $3x+2 \geq -4$ come from?

$\left| x \right| = c \Rightarrow x= \pm c$. So it would be $3x+2\geq 4 $ or $3x+2 \geq -4$

@ronaldchristenkkson  my answer might be better to show the 'what is the mistake' part :)

$$|x|=c \iff x=\pm c$$
This is true; but what you used is
$$|x|\ge c \iff x\ge \pm c$$
which is false; There is no reason you can replace the "$=$" by "$\ge$". As you have proved in your case solution, $|x|\ge c$ actually implies $x \ge c$ or $x \le -c$.

$\left| x \right| \geq c $ implies $x \leq -c$ and $x \geq c$.

@ronaldchristenkkson you're right; the problem in your argument is that u replaced = by $\ge$ for no reason

@ronaldchristenkkson   edited mistakes

Yes. I now realize $\left| x \right| = c \Leftrightarrow x= \pm c$ only holds for the equal sign. I replaced the equal sign with a equal or greater than sign, which made the definition invalid.

Your statement “By definition, $\left| x \right| =  c \Rightarrow x=\pm c$” is uncorrect, your solution by cases is fine.
The correct statement by definition is indeed what you wrote at first:
$$\left| x \right| =  c \iff x=c$$
when $x\ge 0$ and
$$\left| x \right| =  c \iff -x=c$$
otherwise, that is $\left| x \right| =  c \iff x=\pm c$ but, as noticed, it can't be extended in general to inequalities.

Sorry I fixed it. I meant $\left| x \right| = c \Rightarrow x = \pm c$

We can solve it by the combination of number and shape.
First, draw the graph of function $f(x)=\vert 3x+2 \vert $, which is like the following
The graph
Second, we can get the zero point by solving $3 x+2=0$, and the result is $x_0 = -\frac{2}{3}$.
Third, divide the rhs by the coefficient of x, which is 3 in this case, and get the result $d = \frac{4}{3}$.
At last, the two bounds are $x_0 \pm d$. Thus, the answer is $x \in (-\infty, -2] \cup[\frac{2}{3},\infty)$.
In conclusion, to solve the problems in the form $\vert ax+b\vert \ge c$ (suppose $a > 0$), the answer is $x \in (-\infty,-\frac{c + b}{a}) \cup [\frac{c - b}{a},\infty)$
